# Improvement of the database model

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `brand` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `custombrand` (
  `brand_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The brand table contains brand names. These are for all customers if the customer_id is NULL. Additional customer-specific brands can be added. The customer_id is set for them. The custombrand table can contain custom names for the brands whose customer_id is NULL in the brand table.

My query to get alle the brand names for customer with id=2 is:

```
SELECT
    b.id AS id,
    IFNULL(cb.name, b.name)
FROM
    brand b
LEFT JOIN custombrand cb ON b.id = cb.brand_id AND cb.customer_id = 2
WHERE b.customer_id IS NULL OR b.customer_id = 2
ORDER BY id ASC
```

I don't have the feeling that my implementation is that good, but I can't think of a better one either. It is important that these brands are all present. However, it should also be possible for customers to assign their own names to these brands.

I get the correct results:

```
id |   name
---------------
1  |   Brand--Customer_2
2  |   Brand B
3  |   Brand C
4  |   Brand D
5  |   Brand E
```

I get the correct results. However, think there is a much more elegant solution.

Comment: i can't see why you need for the bridge table also a name

Comment: I see common M:N relation. So I cannot understand why DB uses so crooked scheme.

Comment: The two tables are the same. Just use the first table, but add a `custom boolean not null default false` column

Comment: Your tables are missing primary keys.